# Automatic mail after user registration (voucher)

Tags: contacts, system-workflow-messages

not the civi-guru, but with some basic knowledge ;-). 
I would like to send an automated mail when a new user registers.

I have created a profile for that, see http://www.centcom.net/civicrm/index.php,

in the advanced settings, there is  an option for sending a mail after registration, but i would need to send a email template, which i have created in Administration/CiviMail/Templates.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Via Administration/System/planned Jobs?

Thank you,

Gerald
Modify message

Comment: pls clarify in Question who the email is going to, eg the person who registered, or an admin. Also let us know your CMS

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do this through civi native, take a look at CiviCoop's [CiviRules](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules) extension.

Comment: Agreed!  CiviRules plus the "Email API" extension will do this.